# How to combine multiple cells into a single text сell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': [1, 1,2,2], 
                   'user': [1,2,2,1], 
                   'appraisal': [4,2,1,3],
                   'feedback' : ['good', 'bad', 'bad', 'well']
                  })
names = ['item', 'user',  'appraisal', 'feedback' ]
df = df[names]
df
```

I want to get a dataframe as below

```
  item  appraisal   feedback
0   1      3       good bad
1   2      2       bad well
```

Where 'item' is 'item' from df, 'appraisal' is average of df.appraisal for items and 'feedback' is combined cells from df.feedback for items
I can get two variales

```
df1 = df.groupby('item')['appraisal'].mean()
```

But how to combine text cells? I can make pivot_table item / user and "feedback" as a value and then add cells user1+user2.....
but the real dataset has many unique values and i don't think it's a best decision
thanx for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [GroupBy.agg()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) method:

```
In [4]: df.groupby('item').agg({'appraisal':'mean','feedback':' '.join})
Out[4]:
      appraisal  feedback
item
1             3  good bad
2             2  bad well
```

or if you need a "flat" DF, use `as_index=False` as [@John Galt has recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314967/how-to-combine-multiple-cells-into-a-single-text-%d1%81ell/41315006#comment69833373_41315006):

```
In [5]: df.groupby('item', as_index=False).agg({'appraisal':'mean','feedback':' '.join})
Out[5]:
   item  appraisal  feedback
0     1          3  good bad
1     2          2  bad well
```

Comment: Neat. And, `groupby(.., as_index=False)` for flat dataframe like OP wanted.

Comment: nice addition!)